# Laptop with Windows 7 and Windows 8 won't boot after blue screen

Tags: windows-7, laptop, boot, windows-8

My laptop (Dell Precision m4600) won't boot. After the initial boot sequence, the screen is black with a blinking cursor in the upper left corner.
I have run diagnostics from the boot menu, but everything looks ok except for the battery which is somewhat weak.
Booted from the installation DVD and tried to restore from safe mode but Windows requires me to choose an install but gives me none to choose from. Repair yielded no positive results either.
Installed OS:es are Windows 7 + Windows 8 (VHD) and the problem started after blue screen in Windows 8.
Any tips on how to resolve the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What was the blue screen error?  Have you checked your disks for corruption/failure?

Comment: Not sure where to find error message for blue screen on Win8 (the actual screen only displayed sad emoticon with "sorry" text). No error found on disks during diagnostic run.

Comment: you ran dual boot with the vhd? Is it trying to boot into Win8 or Win7?

Comment: Yes I did. I don't know which of the two it's trying to boot into, probably it hasn't decided yet when it hangs in the black screen with the blinking cursor.

Comment: what happens if you press F8 (safemode) on bootup?

Comment: Nothing happens on F8 unless I boot from DVD in which case I can start in safe mode. Problem is that it can't find any installation so I can't do a repair. Guess the boot sector is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert Windows 8 installation media and boot from it.
2. Select Repair and go to command prompt.
3. Attach VHD using **diskpart**.
4. Run these two commands:

**bootsect /nt60 all**

**bcdboot v:\windows**

where v: is mounted VHD drive (change drive letter to match your mappings).

Hope this helps.

---

**Note:**

Eventually you have to run

**sfc /scannow** (again from Windows 8 repair console)

if you cannot boot to Win8 after repair steps above.

Comment: Didn't work either, still freezes after reboot. Thanks anyway.